# Accessing htmlElement in ShadowDom in Dart Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

i'm quite new to Dart and Polymer and have a question i couldn't find an answer for.

I'm writing a simple single page application and want to access a buttonElement in the shadowDom of a polymer element. ( SDK 1.0 and Polymer 0.9.3, Dart Stable Version )

Like i understood from the docs and api i should use :

```dart
@override
void enteredView() {
  super.enteredView();
  submitButton = $['submitButton'];
  submitButton.disabled = true;
}
```

Now heres my html :

```html
<polymer-element name="..." attributes="..." >
  <template>
    ...
    <template repeat="{{ ... in ... }}">
      ...
    </template>
    <template if="{{...}}">
      ...
      <button id="submitButton" on-click="{{...}}">...</button>
    </template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

In this template, when i print out $['submitButton'] at the end of enteredView method i get null.

BUT : when i change my html template and dont put the button in a nestend template tag :

```html
<polymer-element name="..." attributes="..." >
  <template>
    ...
    <template repeat="{{ ... in ... }}">
      ...
    </template>
    <template if="{{...}}">
      ...
    </template>
    <button id="submitButton" on-click="{{...}}">...</button>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

i get my button and can work with it. Otherwise the last call in enteredView ( button.disabled ) throws an error.

Can anyone help me with that ? what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

Just enabling / disabled the button can be done using a special expression in Dart for the disabled attribute.

```
<button disabled?="{{buttonDisabled}}">
```

This will result in removing and adding the disabled attribute.
Finding the Element in a if or repeat template still doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing elements inside `<template repeate="...">` or `template if="...">` doesn't work yet using the `$['id']` method.
There was a discussion about this recently in the Dart group. I thought there should be a feature request too but was not yet able to find them.

I'm not sure if shadowRoot.querySelector('#id') works.

If not then AFAIK the only option is `MutationObserver` like here [dart-polymer-dart-examples / web / mutation_observers /](https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/76f5e9a72c95d292f4fb3b97f246864fcb263634/web/mutation_observers) as you can't access an element before it was inserted into the DOM.

**Edit:**

- [the discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/vRt2AxALmA0)
- [the bug](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/387)

Comment: thanks for the response! I'll try this out
edit : `submitButton = querySelector('#submitButton');` 
Also doesn't work.

Comment: Did the `<template if='expr'>` evaluate to `true` when you tried?
If you just want to enable/disable the button you can bind the `disabled` attribute to a value of your elements class `<button id="submitButton" disabled?={{btnSubmitDisabled}}>` and in your code `@observable bool btnSubmitDisabled = true;`. Then you don't even need to get a reference to the button itself.

Comment: Yes i just want to disable / enable the button and tried first what you suggested, because i think its the cleanest one. But `<button disabled="false">` still is disabled, because the html spec for a disabled button needs to have a "disabled" attribute, anything that stands in "disabled" will result in a disabled button. Yes the expression evaluated to true, otherwise i wouldn't see the button.
I'll try the MutationObserver this evening, thanks for all the links !

Comment: Polymer provides support for such boolean properties but you have to add a '?' before the '='.

Comment: Okay thanks this works. I thought that there must be an aquivalent to the solution from WebUI i found on the web. I'll post the answer in the top post.